# Nginx conflicting server name race condition

Tags: nginx

In the same `nginx.conf` I have a server block for:

```
server {
    server_name *.mysite.com
    ...
}
```

and:

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.mysite.com
    ...
}
```

Will there be a conflict? Or the more specific `server_name` will win the race condition? Is there any significance to the order they appear in the config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No race condition or nothing of that sort will happen.
There is precedence defined for this.

**order of precedence:**

1. exact name
2. longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g. “*.example.org”
3. longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “mail.*”
4. first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in a configuration file)

More on how NGNIX processes requests: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: My nginx begs to differ... `nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "subdomain.example.org" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored"`.